# python string splitting "string of about 80k characters"

Tags: string, python-3.x, list

some samples of data are here

```
f = "optimal after sales service. Our customer friendly support system is truly one of a kind giving A Avon Watches a pride of place in the world of Indian watches.\\t0210PBH2YCA\\t1002004\\t499\\t\\t2015-02-10 16:43:27 IST\\t\\ty\\t1\\t\\t\\t11\\t\\t\\t\\tB00TFCNTGG\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\tB00TFCNTGG\\t\\t\\t\\tAMAZON_IN\\t\\tMigrated Template\\tActive\\t499.0\\nA Avon Sports Digital Black Dial Men\\\'s watch - 1002008\\tMulti functional Design Watch For Children\\\'s ; Tough Watch Case ; Stainless Steel Back ;Power Battery ; Tab For Date,Month & Multiple Light Effect ; Day & Time Display Together ; Stop Watch ; Calendar ; 12-24 Hour Time Display Option. A Avon Watches are Well known for amazing style and powerful features. The inbuilt features specify their usability. The elegantly designed A Avon Watches are apt to complement formal wear. A Avon Watches built with fine skills is backed by optimal after sales service. Our customer friendly support system is truly one of a kind giving A Avon Watches a pride of place in the world of Indian watches.\\t0216PZ3I06Y\\t1002008\\t499\\t\\t2015-02-16 15:45:58 IST\\t\\ty\\t5\\t\\t\\t11\\t\\t\\t\\tB00TOCAJ4C\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t52E478CC519D7B2D\\t\\t\\t\\tAMAZON_IN\\t\\tMigrated Template\\tActive\\t499.0\\nA Avon Sports Digital Black Dial Women\\\'s Watch - 1002013\\tWatch Design For Children, Boys & Girls. A Avon Watches are Well known for amazing style and powerful features. The inbuilt features specify their usability. The elegantly designed A Avon Watches are apt to complement formal wear. A Avon Watches built with fine skills is backed by optimal after sales service. Our customer friendly support system is truly one of a kind giving A Avon Watches a pride of place in the world of Indian watches.\\t0216PZCK1E4\\t1002013\\t599\\t\\t2015-02-16 18:17:39 IST\\t\\ty\\t5\\t\\t\\t11\\t\\t\\t\\tB00TOGJ00M\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t52E49B861FA1FF25\\t\\t\\t\\tAMAZON_IN\\t\ "
z=f.split("\\\t")
for i in z:
  print(i)
  print(len(z))
```

but it is not splitting it is printing same file as it is.
I checked the length of z as well it is showing 1.

How to do that?

Comment: The code you posted throws an exception, it does *not* show a length of 1.

Comment: `.readlines()` returns a list of lines, calling `.split` on that will raise an Exception.

Comment: hi @L3viathan  i have made some changes instead of file i decleared as string in that also it is not splitting the strings.?

Comment: Remove one of your backslashes: `\\\t` -> `\\t`. Otherwise you split on a backslash followed by a tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text does not contain any tabs `'\t'`so why would a split happen? There are a lot of backslashes `\\` followed by a simple `t`, yet you try to split on backslashes followed by a tab. You can try:

```
f.split('\\t')
```

and see the difference.

Comment: it is not working on backslashes also. i tried that too.